# How do I set a default Answer strategy with Mockk

Tags: java, unit-testing, kotlin, mockito, mockk

In Mockito, I can create a mock of a class, and specify the default answer for any function calls to that mock, like this:

```
  whenever(this.strings).thenReturn(mock(StringProvider::class.java, StringProviderAnswer()))
```

Where the answer might be

```
    class StringProviderAnswer : Answer<Any?> {
    private val delegate = Mockito.RETURNS_DEFAULTS!!

    override fun answer(invocation: InvocationOnMock?): Any? {
        val invocationMethodReturn = invocation?.method?.returnType
        val stringType = String::class.java
        return when (invocationMethodReturn) {
            stringType -> invocation.method?.name.toString() + invocation.arguments.joinToString()
            else -> delegate.answer(invocation)
        }
    }
}
```

So I can stub out all the functions of a class in a very detailed way.  Is there a way to do this with Mockk?  I see that there is an `Answer` class, but I don't see an obvious way to create a mock that will except that as the default answer strategy.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand correctly, you want a mock that returns the method name and the arguments whenever the return type is `String`, and a default value otherwise.

The second branch of your `when` statement is easily attainable with a relaxed mock, i.e. mocking your class with `mockk(YourClass::class, relaxed = true)` or annotating your mock with `@RelaxedMockK` instead of `@MockK`.

As for the first branch, mockk currently does not support stubbing all methods that have a return type: I think the only way you have to implement such a behavior would be doing

```
every { 
    yourMock.method(any())
} answers { 
    method.name + args.joinToString(" ") 
}
```

for every method in your mocked class.

It shouldn't be too hard to add a parameter to the `mockk` function to define a strategy that overrides the `DefaultAnswerer`, I'd gladly review a PR about it.

Comment: That'd be great.  Can you point me in the right direction?  Where in the does the default answer strategy get set up for a class mock?

Comment: The answer strategy is in the `answer` method of the MockKStub class: https://github.com/mockk/mockk/blob/42cbe60e534d76bb4922188447a07b83a7bfc07e/mockk/common/src/main/kotlin/io/mockk/impl/stub/MockKStub.kt#L37

I think you can add an answer strategy object to the MockKStub class and use it there if it is populated.

Answer (score 0):

This is now possible with [reflective-mockk](https://episode6.github.io/reflective-mockk/) (an add-on library for mockk). The cleanest approach would probably be to only stub the methods that return Strings.

```
val mock = reflectiveMockk<SomeObject> {
  answerEveryCallIn(normalMemberFunctions.filterReturnType<String>()) {
    method.name + args.joinToString()
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you could provide a defaultAnswer for all methods, but then you need to account for the other possible return types...

```
val mock = reflectiveMockk<SomeObject> {
    defaultAnswer {
        when (method.returnType) {
          String::class -> method.name + args.joinToString()
          Unit::class -> Unit
          else -> null // unsafe
        }
    }
}
```

See https://episode6.github.io/reflective-mockk/ for more samples.

**WARNING** reflective-mockk is currently powered by a reflection hack on mockK. If you like it and want it to be officially "supported," please add a comment on this mockK PR: https://github.com/mockk/mockk/pull/1005, which would remove the need for our hack.